# Can I do both Wakeful and Non Wakeful works inside WakefulIntentService alternatively

Tags: android, service, commonsware-cwac

Suppose i want to run both wakeful and non wakeful service alternatively.

Something like a toggle button. If its On then i have to start my [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) with `doWakefulWork()` method.
 And if its off then I have to do all same tasks in same `WakefulIntentService` but with a different method which don't interact with CPU and wifi in sleep mode something like non wakeful work in my word..

I just added a new method in my Service, but unable to go forward.

```
public class NetworkCommunicationService extends WakefulIntentService{
private static String UserID;

public NetworkCommunicationService() {
   super("NetworkCommunicationService");
}

@Override
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
    if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(this))
       new SyncValidater().execute();
}

/**I have to do something like this....  */
protected void doNonWakefulWork() {
    if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(this))
       new SyncValidater().execute();
}
```

Is their any solution for this... Or I have to create a new service to do the non wakeful work.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose i want to run both wakeful and non wakeful service alternatively

It is not clear to me what situation would make sense for this. `WakefulIntentService` does not support this scenario (or, if it does, it is by accident, not intention).

I would recommend [switching to `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html). Then, when you want the service to run "wakefully", follow the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` recipe and call `startWakefulService()`. If you want the service to run normally, just have the receiver call `startService()`. Note, though, that there is a chance that the service will not get an opportunity to run in this case, if the device falls asleep before the service starts.

Comment: i was unable to understand the "run service normally" part. can you explain a little with a small example.

Comment: @user3678972: "run service normally" == "run the service without it using a `WakeLock` to keep the device awake"

Comment: No i mean how and where I call the startService() ? inside onReceive() or from the activity from where I started the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @user3678972: I was thinking calling it consistently from `onReceive()`, so your "start the service" logic is all in one place, and it is merely a question of which method you use to start it.